# Google Cloud Platform Custom Domains

Tags: dns, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I setup my custom domain in Google Cloud Platform within the settings area for App Engine and updated my dns entries with my domain name provider.  When I type my domain I get a blank page with the error: "The requested URL / was not found on this server".

Is it even possible to map a custom domain to a specific instance running in compute engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.  Similar to setting the dns for app engine: https://docs.bitnami.com/google/faq/#how-to-configure-a-custom-domain

shows an example that can be used for any instance type.